# Make layout unscrollable when GestureOverlayView is touched

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, gesture

In `FragmentA`, I have a scrollable layout. Inside the layout, I have
`GestureOverlayView`.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/signGesture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fadeEnabled="false"
                android:fadeOffset="10000"
                android:gestureColor="@color/black"
                android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
                android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```

Is there a way to make the layout unscrollable when `GestureOverlayView` is touched ? I can't draw anything because the layout is moving !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OnGesturePerformedListener` on your gesture view and there you disable your `scrollView` scrolling by returning `true` on the touch listener

```
gesture.addOnGesturePerformedListener(new OnGesturePerformedListener() {

    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView v, Gesture g) {

        mScrollView.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
          {
                return true;
          }
        });
    }

});
```

**EDIT**

You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610886/7940639) , it actually present a custom ScrollView that will intercept the scroll touch and disable it when you perform gesture listener.

Comment: Yes, is same. Just wonder why you use `addOnGesturePerformedListener` ?

Comment: `addOnGesturePerformedListener` is just a suggestion, you can use what you are already using. And you are right, this won't work because the scrollview action will be performed after the gesture listener is complete. I will update the answer.

Comment: @JohnJoe Can you post you gesture logic ?

Comment: Thanks. There are no logic for the gesture.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it.

Comment: Any time :) . Tell me the output when you try it .

Comment: I'm using Fragment, does this answer helped ?

Comment: Yes there is no problem

Comment: Thanks,the link you sent is helped

Comment: I'm glad it helps you :)